# Проектирование БД. Выделение отдельной таблицы

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Есть различного рода операции с кассой. Всего 4 различных операций.
Базу спроектировал следующим образом:

Таблицы:
 1. safe_transaction
 2. safe_type1_transaction (sft_id)
 3. safe_type2_transaction (sft_id)

sft_id - это поле, ссылающееся на safe_transaction отношением ManyToOne.

Есть два типа, содержащих специфичные инпуты, поэтому их выделил в отдельные таблицы (safe_type1_transaction, safe_type2_transaction).
Сумма операции может быть во всех таблицах. Поэтому для вычисления остатка в кассе необходимо выполнить два JOIN'a c таблицами safe_type1_transaction, safe_type2_transaction.

Не лучше выделить все суммы(деньги) в отдельную таблицу для того, чтобы избавиться от джоинов или это только усложнит схему БД?

Comment: Да, все операции с деньгами лучше держать в одной таблице, что бы легче считать было. А вот "выделить" или "скопировать" это другой вопрос. Если так удобнее, то вполне возможно что сами суммы или что то позволяющее их вычислить были в 2 и 3 таблицах, а триггера на них клали итоговые суммы в общую таблицу

Comment: Удобней хранить в 3-х таблицах. И вероятность того, что этих таблиц будет больше не велика.
Да и считать в принципе несложно - нужно только одно условие на проверку типа транзакции (CASE WHEN).